# Custom form authetication logoff redirection to another page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net mvc 5 and using custom form authetication. When I try to login it login perfectly but when I try to logoff it redirect me to logiurl which I have set in webconfig file which is give below.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="30" />
</authentication>
```

Rather than take me to the page for which redirection is defined in Logoff action method as shown below.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Logoff()
{
 _formsAuth.SignOut();
 return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Everything is working fine in chrome browser but it is not working in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

this method as been deprecated, tho it is useful for testing, i'm not using it anymore and rather use the already implement template which I customize to my own, when it comes to security, customers comes first.

that being said, I'm left with unanswered question about classes and models that you use.

Using the forms authentication feature requires calls to two static methods of the System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication class:

- The Authenticate method validates credentials supplied by the user.
- The SetAuthCookie method adds a cookie to the response to the
  browser, so that users do not need to authenticate every time they
  make a request.

> ```
> public class FormsAuthProvider : IAuthProvider {
>     public bool Authenticate(string username, string password){
>         bool result = FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(username, password);
>         if (result) {
>             FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
>         }
>         return result;
>     }
>
>
> public class AccountController : Controller {
>     IAuthProvider authProvider;
>     public AccountController(IAuthProvider auth) {
>         authProvider = auth;
>     }
>     public ViewResult Login() {
>         return View();
>     }
>     [HttpPost]
>     public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl) {
>         if (ModelState.IsValid) {
>             if (authProvider.Authenticate(model.UserName, model.Password)) {
>
>                 return Redirect(returnUrl ?? Url.Action("Index", "Admin"));
>             } else {
>                 ModelState.AddModelError("", "Incorrect username or password");
>                 return View();
>             }
>         } else {
>             return View();
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```